# method of a pointer pointing to an object is inaccesible

Tags: c++

my class looks like this

```
class A{
private:
    int id;
public:
    A();
    int getId();
}

class B{
private:

public:
  B();
}
```

Implementation

```
//constructor
    B::B() : A(){
    }
```

B extends A class.

Okay in my main cpp I have a function like this

```
bool checkID(B *obj){
    if(obj->getId() > 1){ return true; } else { return false; }

}
```

However, the obj->**getId()** , getId() says its inaccesible.

Why is it?

Comment: In addition to the other comments/answers below, change `return obj->getID() > 1;`. The result of this expression is already a boolean, no need to check if it's true and then return true or, when false, return false.

Comment: What compiler did you use. Because this code does not compile with g++, it unsuprisingly reports `error: type A is not a direct base of B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default C++ uses private inheritance. Use B : public A to publicly inherit from A. Also you need to define the inheritance in the declaration.

```
class B : public A {
 public:
  B();
}
```

Comment: ah i see. i thought it was public by default. thanks.

Comment: public, private, or protected, if you don't specify that one class derives from the other the compiler won't do it for you ;-)

Comment: It was surprising me that the compiler says it is inaccesible, so apparently it knows it deriving from A due to the constructor. Or do I miss something?

Comment: I'm actually even surprised that `B::B() : A()` compiles when B does not derive from A....dunno what it means.

Answer (score 0):

B must derive from A to have A's members be accessible from B objects.

```
class B : public A { ... };
```